# Calculate NDVI in a large feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, large-datasets

I'm having some trouble with my GEE script. I have to calculate NDVI of each feature of my shapefile, but it is too large. Someone could help me with this code? I think it's king of simple, but I'm just learning how to use GEE...

Here is my error message: Image (Error)
Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many edges (2247249 > 2000000).

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fddd403dc034cb74c01f5f650a680f3c

Comment: Please also include the pertinent portions of code in the body of text. That way your question remains valid even if the link goes 404. Have you considered simplifying the polygon geometry?: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-polygon-simplify

Answer (score 2):

I used some extra lines to simplify your geometry and your error is gone
However, a new error occurred which I don't know how to solve:

> Image (Error)
>
> User memory limit exceeded

.

It's not the perfect solution but firstly try the code below to reach the next error.

```
// Get a feature collection.
var featureCol = ee.FeatureCollection(veredas);

// Simplify each feature in the collection, by mapping the
// .simplify() function over it. 
var simplifiedCol = featureCol.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.simplify({maxError: 100});
});

var filt_lt5 = LT5TOA.filterBounds(simplifiedCol)//filter by area- using the created point
    .filterDate('1984-01-01','2012-05-05')
    .median();//filter by date- requires a start and end date string

var filt_lt8 = LT8TOA.filterBounds(simplifiedCol)//filter by area- using the created point
    .filterDate('2013-04-11','2021-04-27')
    .median();
    

var NDVI_LT5 = filt_lt5.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']);

var NDVI_LT8 = filt_lt8.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']);

print(NDVI_LT8)

var vis = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
              '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
              '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];


print(NDVI_LT5)

Map.addLayer(NDVI_LT5)
```